# Filter response of API so I only get a single value

Tags: javascript, list

Hay i need to filter an api im basicly not into javascript or something so i just tried a bit for a few hours :P.
This is what i got till now https://jsfiddle.net/g8f6px7a/6/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$.getJSON("https://api.crypto-bridge.org/api/v1/ticker", function(data){
var pollo = '';
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
pollo += value.id+' Last Price: ';
pollo += value.last+' Volume: ';
pollo += value.volume;

pollo += '<br>';
});
$('#demo').append(pollo);

});
  });
```

Now i need only the Value of HTRC_BTC how can i filter out the rest can anyone help me with it? :)

Comment: `if(value.id === "HTRC_BTC") {` ...

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/g8f6px7a/11/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.getJSON("https://api.crypto-bridge.org/api/v1/ticker", function(data) {
    var pollo = '';
    console.log(data);
    for (x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
      value = data[x];
      if (value.id === "HTRC_BTC") {
        pollo += value.id + ' Last Price: ';
        pollo += value.last + ' Volume: ';
        pollo += value.volume;

        pollo += '<br>';
      }
    };

    $('#demo').append(pollo);

  });
});
```